# Define a very large 2D array array with double type

Tags: c, arrays

I want to define a 2D array with size 20*100000 in C. I do not want to keep the size fixed.

Comment: Have you got some code to share with us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double **twod = malloc(20 * sizeof(double *));
int i;
if (twod == NULL)
    abort();

for (i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
    if ((twod[i] = malloc(100000 * sizeof(double))) == NULL)
        abort();

// clean up
for (i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
    free(twod[i]);
free(twod);
```

The first `malloc` call allocates space for 20 `double` pointers. Each `double` pointer will point to a subarray.

The second `malloc` call in the loop allocates 100000 `double`s in each subarray.

The `free` calls do the inverse of `malloc`--they return memory to free store. First, each subarray must be freed, in a loop. Then the entire array itself must be freed too.

The return value of `malloc` is examined against `NULL`. If `malloc` returns `NULL`, then the system is out of memory. This is important since you are allocating HUGE amounts of memory. If `malloc` returns `NULL`, the application is aborted.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to define a pointer to pointer and initialize it like this:

```
int i;
double **array;
array = malloc(sizeof(double *)) * 20);
for (i=0; i<20; i++) {
    array[i] = malloc(sizeof(double) * 100000);
}
```

Don't forget to `free` the memory when you're done with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Variable-length array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) (since C99) in order to avoid fragmentation:

```
double (*array)[cols];

array = malloc(sizeof(*array) * rows);
```

In this way calling `free(array);` is enough.